# How can we do a test automation with IVR systems?

Tags: automated-tests, ivr

What is the way to implement a test automation with an IVR system?

Is there a specific product?

we are using ININ products but it seems there is no guidance other than manual user testing.

Do you have any product suggestions and test automation suggestions with ININ environment?

Comment: checkout these blogs: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/63057-173552389 and http://cyara.com/what_we_do/ivr-speech-testing/ you may get some information.

Comment: Do your IVR is based on SIP ?

Comment: yes. what are the possibilities on that?